# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9 w/Hibernate 3 & Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, nvarchar

We recently started seeing this error for an application which was previously working.  No code changes have been made to cause the error, nor database changes (to my knowledge).  There was supposedly some fairly recent change made to the server's datasource configuration (driver version) but I have no definite details.

The application does NOT have any nvarchar2 columns in the tables being used in the failing operations.
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: Post full stacktrace. Sometimes the cause is a field in the select list of a  `SQLQuery`

Comment: Not an option. Also I'm pretty sure there isn't any mention of that there (otherwise I'd probably have it fixed by now).

Comment: Without extra infos is pretty hard give you other advices, sorry

Comment: It's an environmental/driver issue apparently - stack trace doesn't offer much help. Hibernate is reading the result set metadata and doesn't know what NVARCHAR is.  Maybe a driver difference, since w/two different app servers connecting to the same db and same code deployed, one works and the other does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom hibernate dialect with this in the constructor "fixed" this problem.  Still no idea why it appeared, no NVARCHAR columns are being used...

```
registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StringType.INSTANCE.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining the root cause of this.
More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/global.htm#CHDHHJDB

I was able to solve this by using a different version of Oracle JDBC driver.
Downgrade of ojdbc6.jar from “11.2.0.3.0” that was on the prod server to “11.1.0.7.0-Production” used for development fixed this. The target server is NLS_RDBMS_VERSION    10.2.0.4.0